# Writing an ATM script - how do I get it to loop back out to the user options?

Tags: python-3.x

Still a beginner with Python. 7 Weeks into an 8 week course. My assignment was to polish my previous assignment. What I'm trying to add is not required, but I think it would be good practice to always aim for the best UI possible. I currently have a functional ATM script that works fine, once, then it must be restarted to use one of the other functions. What I want to do is somehow call the user_options dictionary I created to prompt the user to see if they want to perform another task while the ATM program is still running.

To clarify, I would like the program to be able to start, prompt the user, run the function the user selects, then loop back out to the prompt for another input.

If I change the user_options dict to a function, I don't know how to do it. Sorry for rambling, anyway, here is my code:

```
import sys

account_balance = float(500.25)

# defines theprintbalance function
def balance():
  print("Your current balance:\n" + str(account_balance)) 

#defines the deposit function
def deposit():
    global account_balance
    #input paramaters for deposit
    deposit_amount = input("How much would you like to deposit today?\n") 
    #modifies account balance with deposit ammount
    account_balance += float(deposit_amount)
    #prints the deposit amount and current blanace
    print("Deposit was $" + str('%.2f' % float(deposit_amount)) + ", current 
    balance is $" + str(account_balance))

#defines withdrawal function
def withdrawal():
  global account_balance
  #input paramaters for withdrawal
  withdrawal_amount = input("How much would you like to withdraw today?\n") 
  #if statement for withdrawal amount that exceeds balance
  if float(withdrawal_amount) > account_balance:
    print("$" + str('%.2f' % float(withdrawal_amount)) + " is greater than 
    your account balance of $" + str('%.2f' % float(account_balance)))
    #restarts the withdrawl
    print('Please enter an amount less than or equal to your current balance 
    for withdrawal')
    withdrawal()
  #else statement for successful withdrawal
  else:
    account_balance -= float(withdrawal_amount)
    print("Withdrawal amount was $" + str('%.2f' % float(withdrawal_amount)) 
    + ", current balance is $" + str('%.2f' % float(account_balance)))

#defines quit function
def quit():
  #prints quit message
  print("Thank you for banking with us.") 

#creates user input dict and removes previously used if/else loop
user_options = input("What would you like to do? (B)alance, (W)ithdrawal, 
(D)eposit, (Q)uit\n")

options = {'B': balance,
           'b': balance,
           'W': withdrawal,
           'w': withdrawal,
           'D': deposit,
           'd': deposit,
           'Q': quit,
           'q': quit,
}

options[user_options]()
```

If anyone has ideas or suggestions, that'd be great. This is PURELY a cosmetic thing that I want to add to the program. I don't think I'll be graded any differently on it. I just want to learn.

Comment: Do you want actions to happen one after another, or several concurrently?

Comment: I want the user to be able to check their balance, then be given the option to deposit, make a withdrawal, or quit without having to restart the program.

Comment: Have a look at a ``while`` loop, specifically wrapping everything after ``user_options `` in a ``while True:`` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a while loop which would include all the options they have. Once they have completed whatever option they chose to do, break out of the loop and have send the user back the the beginning of the program where they can choose to exit the ATM or run another option.